# How to create an Aura DI container?

Tags: php, auraphp

I installed a composer, downloaded the Aura, created an index.pxp and wrote in it:

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');

use Aura\Di\ContainerBuilder;
$builder = new ContainerBuilder();
$di = $builder->newInstance();

$object = $di->newInstance('Vendor\Package\ClassName');
```

But phpStorm says:`Undefined namespase DI`

And i have error: Fatal error: Class 'Aura\Di\ContainerBuilder' not found in... on line 4

I do as follows: http://auraphp.com/packages/3.x/Di/getting-started.html#1-1-1

Comment: Did you run `composer install`? Is `aura/di` even in your `composer.json` file?

Comment: @Phil no, in my composer.json only `{
    "require": {
        "aura/router": "^3.1"
    }
}`

Comment: Why would you be surprised then that it can't find `\Aura\Di`? I suggest you start with `composer require aura/di`

Comment: @Phil is correct here. May be mark it as an answer ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the composer auto-loader to pick up `\Aura\Di`, the dependency needs to be managed by composer.

You can easily do this by executing

```
composer require aura/di
```

which will add the dependency to your `composer.json` file and register with the auto-loader.

---

If you have manually downloaded and installed aura/di, you can revert that.